# Printing Time since Epoch in Nanoseconds

Tags: c, time, epoch

So I know how to print time since epoch in seconds, and evidently even milliseconds, but when I try nanoseconds I keep getting bogus output of an integer that's way too small, and it sometimes prints numbers smaller than the last run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void)
{
    long int ns;
    struct timespec spec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec);
    ns = spec.tv_nsec;;

    printf("Current time: %ld nonoseconds since the Epoch\n", ns);
    return 0;
}
```

For instance, with a run from this I got 35071471 nanoseconds since epoch.

Any help with getting this to display correctly would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The nanosecond part is just the "fractional" part, you have to add  the seconds, too.

```
// otherwise gcc with option -std=c11 complaints
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#define BILLION  1000000000L
int main(void)
{
  long int ns;
  uint64_t all;
  time_t sec;
  struct timespec spec;

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec);
  sec = spec.tv_sec;
  ns = spec.tv_nsec;

  all = (uint64_t) sec * BILLION + (uint64_t) ns;

  printf("Current time: %" PRIu64  " nanoseconds since the Epoch\n", all);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: One more thing, is it possible to cast `all` as a `char`? What I'm trying to do gives me a segmentation fault when I try to cast it

Comment: `all` is an eight byte large integer and an enormously large number, too. Why do you want it as a one byte small `char`?

Comment: I'm trying to build up a log message, with the time since epoch as part of the message. Unless I can strcpy/strcat an `uint64_t`, I need it as a `char` because it's going to be part of a data structure element with type `char`

Edit: I mean `char *`, I need it to be a string

Comment: @WolvenOmega you have to convert it to a string. make a buffer that is large enough `char buffer[21] = {'\0'};` and convert with e.g.: `sprintf(buffer,"%"PRIu64"",all);`