# Custom date and time including nanoseconds

Tags: c, time, high-resolution-clock, high-resolution-time

For this program I need to "grab the start time of the entire process within the max. time precision avail including nanoseconds." in the format:

```
April 9, 2022 13:18:17.123456789
```

I am able to get everything but the nanoseconds. Is it possible and/or what do you recommend?

Here is what I have:

```
//%B - Full Month Name
//%e - day space padded (%d 0 padded)
//$G - year (with century)
//%R - 24-hour HH:MM time, equivalent to %H:%M
//%N - nanoseconds?
//%T - ISO 8601 time format (HH:MM:SS), equivalent to %H:%M:%S

#define BUFFERSIZE 256

char timeStringEnd[BUFFERSIZE] = {0};

time_t timeEnd = time(NULL);

struct tm *timePointerEnd = localtime(&timeEnd);

strftime(timeStringEnd, BUFFERSIZE, "\n%B%e, %G %T", timePointerEnd);

puts(timeStringEnd);
```

`%N` doesn't want to work. Any supplemental material/sources on using timing is much appreciated . TIA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing Time since Epoch in Nanoseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439268/printing-time-since-epoch-in-nanoseconds)

Comment: Succinctly — no, that doesn't answer the question relevantly.  It prints a single number, not a formatted date/time as requested here.

Comment: @IłyaBursov although I agree with Jonathan, that is very helpful. Thank you for your contribution

Comment: Using `localtime()` and printing with `%B%e, %G %T` with lacks a _daylight time_ indication can make subsequent timestamp outputs look liker they step backwards when clocks going from daylight time to standard time.  I recommend to use 1) `gmtime()` or 2) continue with `localtime()` and print with `%z, %Z` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strftime()` function doesn't support sub-second times.  You'll need to add that yourself.  You also need to use a function that returns sub-second times — that isn't `time()`.  Assuming you have a POSIX-ish system, you can use [`clock_gettime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html):

```
struct timespec tv;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tv);
struct tm *timePointerEnd = localtime(&tv.tv_sec);
size_t nbytes = strftime(timeStringEnd, BUFFERSIZE, "\n%B%e, %G %T", timePointerEnd);
snprintf(timeStringEnd + nbytes, sizeof(timeStringEnd) - nbytes,
         "%.9ld", tv.tv_nsec);
puts(timeStringEnd);
```

Note that if you want to print microseconds, you use `%.6ld` and `tm.tv_nsec / 1000`; if you want to print milliseconds, you use `%.3ld` and `tm.tv_nsec / 1000000`. Care is required.

C11 provides the [`timespec_get()`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.2.5) function that does roughly the same job.  It uses a `struct timespec`, but the arguments are slightly different.  You'd pass the pointer first and specify `TIME_UTC` as the second argument.

If you have neither of those functions available, the (old, obsolescent) POSIX function [`gettimeofday()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) provides microsecond resolution timing.  And an even older function, [`ftime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ftime.html), also from POSIX (but removed from the standard nearly two decades ago) provides millisecond resolution timing.  Both of these are often available on non-POSIX systems.  Windows has other functions too.

Comment: Thank you. I was using the timespec in another part of the program to get the start time in seconds and nanoseconds for when a function is called to eventually give me something to calculate the time elapsed. For example, if I wanted to get the total time in-between a timePointerStart and timePointerEnd including the nanoseconds would you recommend I do the nanoseconds math first and then snprintf  the results after?

Comment: I'm torn between saying "that's a new question" and augmenting this answer with code for arithmetic on `struct timespec` structures.  If you want to print the formatted time, that's done using a variant of what's shown above.  If you want to calculate and print the elapsed time, you have to use different code.  What format should the elapsed time be printed in?  `3d 13h 12m 43.912317664s`?  `306763.912317664s`?  No `s` suffix to indicate the units?  Or ISO 8601 'period' (aka 'interval') notation?  Or what?  The arithmetic is easy; the formatting choices are legion!

Comment: Understandable! If you want i'll give it a test first and post another question if need be but the format would be 0s.123456789ns...I think I what I "have" is the secs and nsecs using timespec binded to a struct timespec start and stop...just don't know if there is anything else built in that I could be using.

Comment: There are no standard functions in the POSIX or C libraries specifically for formatting time durations (the gap between two instants in time).

Comment: When using the timespec tm -> clock_gettime(realtime, &tm) im getting this as output: How is seconds 1649528225? and where are the first 2 digits in nanoseconds coming from? ```timespec sec - TIME Second START: 1649528225

timespec nsec - TIME Nano START: 879597000

April 9, 2022 14:17:05879597000```

Comment: Assuming `struct timespec tm; clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME);`, the value in `tm->tv_sec` is a `time_t` value, and will be the same as the value you'd get from `time_t now = time(0);`.  It is the standard "number of seconds since The Epoch — aka 1970-01-01 00:00:00Z".  The value in `tm.tv_nsec` is the fractional part of the second, represented as a value in nanoseconds between 0 and 999,999,999.  When printing that, it is crucial to handle the value correctly, with `%.9ld` or equivalent.  That adds leading zeros so you can distinguish between 0.100000000` and `0.000001000`, etc.

Comment: If you want to print microseconds, then you use `%.6ld` and `tm.tv_nsec / 1000`; if you want to print milliseconds, then you use `%.3ld` and `tm.tv_nsec / 1000000`.  Care is required.

Comment: Oh, okay. I appreciate your help as I have learned a great deal here today. Thanks, that clarifies things for me. So, if my logic is correct, what I was seeing as the first 2 digits were 2 milliseconds followed by the nanoseconds I appended because they are included in the epoch time?

Comment: Probably — that's about the best I can say.  I'm glad my commentary has been some help.  Handling time well is an intricate process — one that requires clarity in understanding exactly what you're seeking as information.

Comment: @jTruBela "total time in-between a timePointerStart and timePointerEnd including the nanoseconds" --> `double diff_in_seconds = difftime(end.tv_sec, start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)/1.0e9`. Then `printf("%.9f seconds\n", diff_in_seconds);`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: With 10 decimal digits required for the number of seconds and 9 for the fractional part, you could run into problems with the number of digits that a `double` can store.  That said, if you're dealing with current measurements, you're unlikely to have numbers of seconds that are so different, but it is worth keeping that in mind.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I hate to rehash things but I was tasked with finding this in a shell script and wonder if I can pick your brain again

Comment: If you've got GNU `date`, you can use `date --rfc-3339=ns` to get the current time specified to nanoseconds.  That doesn't give you options for milliseconds or microseconds.  If you want that level of control, you will have to roll your own.